# trimming all string type columns dynamically of dataframe scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I want to trim only string type columns of DF as trimming all columns will change data type of non string column to string type.
I have 2 ways to do it currently but looking for some good and efficient method.

**First Method**

```scala
var Countrydf = Seq(("Virat               ", 18, "RCB ali shah"), ("             Rohit ", 45, "MI "), (" DK", 67, "KKR ")).toDF("captains", "jersey_number", "teams")

Countrydf.show

for (name <- Countrydf.schema) {
   if (name.dataType.toString == "StringType")
     Countrydf = Countrydf.withColumn(name.name, trim(col(name.name)))
 }
```

**Second Method**

```
val trimmedDF = Countrydf.columns.foldLeft(Countrydf) { (memoDF, colName) =>
  memoDF.withColumn(colName, trim(col(colName)))
}

val exprs = Countrydf.schema.fields.map { f => 
  if (trimmedDF.schema.fields.contains(f)) col(f.name)
  else lit(null).cast(f.dataType).alias(f.name) 
}
trimmedDF.select(exprs: _*).printSchema
```

both works fine and output is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Performance wise best solution I found is**

```
var Countrydf = Seq(("Virat               ",18,"RCB ali shah"),("             Rohit ",45,"MI "),(" DK",67,"KKR ")).toDF("captains","jersey_number","teams")

Countrydf.show

for( name <- Countrydf.schema) {
   if(name.dataType.toString=="StringType")
   Countrydf= Countrydf.withColumn(name.name, trim(col(name.name)))
 }
```